# Xarray how to combine 2 dataset occasionally overlapping temporally, but not spatially?

Tags: python, merge, dataset, dask, python-xarray

[image: Sketch of the problem]

**Context:** I have 2 datacubes (datacube_1, datacube_2) with 3D variables (dimensions `t,y,x`). They do not overlap spatially but their union forms a bigger ensemble (Datacube Combined). They sometimes overlap temporally but not always (black = t1, red = t2, green = t3 and blue = t4). I want to combine those datasets so at each timestamp, if they have values they are simply stitched together, and if not the spatial footprint of the datacube with no values is filled with NaNs. (in the sketch, a filled rectangle represents values, just the outlines represents NaNs).

**Setup:**

- Datacube 1: has values at t1, t3, t4
- Datacube 2: has values at t1, t2, t3
- Datacube Combined: t1 is full, t2 has NaNs for Datacube 1's spatial footprint and full for Datacube 2's, t3 is full, t4 has NaNs for Datacube 2's spatial footprint and full for Datacube 1's.

**Problem:** My goal is to use if possible `chunks` and to have Datacube Combined with the **smallest size** on memory as possible. I do not want to have timestamps simply appended to each other, if they can be combined they should.
Between `merge`, `combine_by_coords`, `concat`, `combine_first` I don't know which one corresponds exactly to what I want to do, which one is the fastest and the most adapted to chunks. **Which method should I use ?**
I read the documentation but honestly I got confused.

**Code:**

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

##### ----- EXAMPLE WITH 2 CUBES ----- #####

# Define the dimensions and coordinates
t_coords1 = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04'], dtype='datetime64') #t1, t3, t4
t_coords2 = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'], dtype='datetime64') #t1, t2, t3
y_coords = np.arange(0, 1000)
x_coords_1 = np.arange(0, 800)  # Different size for datacube_1
x_coords_2 = np.arange(0, 120)  # Different size for datacube_2

# Chunk the datacubes to recreate the error
# Create Datacube 1
datacube_1 = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(len(t_coords1), len(y_coords), len(x_coords_1)),
    dims=['t', 'y', 'x'],
    coords={'t': t_coords1, 'y': y_coords, 'x': x_coords_1},
).chunk({'t': 2, 'y': 100, 'x': 100})

# Create Datacube 2
datacube_2 = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(len(t_coords2), len(y_coords), len(x_coords_2)),
    dims=['t', 'y', 'x'],
    coords={'t': t_coords2, 'y': y_coords, 'x': x_coords_2},
).chunk({'t': 2, 'y': 100, 'x': 100})

# Merge the datacubes (I rewrite datacube_1 because in reality I merge 4 datasets together in a loop)
datacube_1 = datacube_1.merge(datacube_2)



##### ----- EXAMPLE WITH MORE THAN TWO DATACUBES ----- #####
# Gather the names of the datacubes to combine
cubes = ['Datacube_1','Datacube_2','Datacube_3','Datacube_4']

# Load the first datacube so we can combine the others to that one
xrds = xr.open_dataset(cubes[0], chunks=({'t': 500, 'y': 100, 'x': 100})

# Loop over the rest of the datacubes
for n in range(1, len(cubes)):

        # Open the next datacube
        ds_temp = xr.open_dataset(cubes[n], chunks=({'t': 500, 'y': 100, 'x': 100}))
        # Combine it with the other ones
        xrds = xrds.merge(ds_temp)


from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

# Save the dataset that way so it does not overload memory
write_job = ds_temp.to_netcdf("combined_datacube.nc", mode='w', compute=False)
with ProgressBar():
     print(f"Writing the file")
     write_job = write_job.compute()
```